# Do simulated values for IV need to be linked to the simulated series of underlying prices when used together in a Monte Carlo Simulation?

Tags: implied-volatility, monte-carlo, simulations, geometric-brownian

I've been using thousands of simulated stock price series generated with mean and standard deviation of daily returns and Geometric Brownian Motion, and then running these simulated price series through the Bjerksund Stensland 2002 option pricing model to generate thousands of simulations of option prices.

Up to this point, I have assumed constant IV for the IV input in the option pricing model, though I would like to use a simulated series of values for IV in the same way I currently am with the price of the underlying (if this is indeed advantageous...perhaps it isn't).

My question: if I am to do this, can the IV series be generated using its own mean and standard deviation in the same way I would generate prices for the underlying, or do the simulated values for IV have to be in lockstep with my simulated price series such that simulated price declines usually see an uptick in IV, rises in simulated price see a downturn in IV, etc.?  In other words, can both simulated price and IV be on their own independent random walks, or does simulated IV have to be a function of underlying price to reflect this generally inverse relationship between the price of the underlying and IV?

If it's relevant, my plan is to simply use mean / standard deviation of daily VIX returns for generating the simulated IV series as I don't have access to symbol-specific IV data. If this way of doing things is problematic and a waste of time, feel free to let me know!

Comment: If you are going to simulate the volatility process, you must make sure that you use the same simulated volatility to generate your price paths, otherwise you are not being consistent / you're making a very specific and odd assumption.

Comment: @will When you say that I must use the same simulated volatility to generate my price paths, do you mean the price path of the underlying or the price path of the option? I would naturally use the simulated volatility as an input to the option pricing model, but if you meant the price path of the underlying, are you saying that one should use simulated iv to generate the path of the underlying? Wouldn't it be better to do it the other way around (get underlying prices and then use that to generate IV path)? Or can I generate both paths independently,and over 10,000 or so runs get a decent sim?